# Having collectionViewCell.label.text Change Every Second with Timer

Tags: swift, timer, uicollectionview, label, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently learning to code swift apps and am trying to do some projects on my own. My current personal challenge is to do a countdown timer app. The concept is simple: the user enters a date, from a UIDatePicker, and the app shows the time remaining until his list of various events (uses user default values to keep the events in memory). All the said events are shown in a collection view (see below for screen shots).

I ran into something too complicated for my actual skillset and I thought you guys probably would have the answer, or at least a few suggestions! Here is my issue: **I'd like for the time remaining between today and the event to decrease every second, and to be shown through a label inside a collectionViewCell.** I found a very simple way to do so, with a timer, but implementing the said solution with a collectionViewCell is giving me quite the headache.

Here are the code excerpts I'd like to share, and hopefully it's enough:

```
@objc func UpdateTimeLabel(index: Int) -> String {
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = userCalendar.timeZone
    
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "dates")![index] as! String)!
    
    let timeLeft = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: date)

    return "\(timeLeft.day!) days \(timeLeft.hour!) hours \(timeLeft.minute!) minutes \(timeLeft.second!) seconds"
    
}
```

That's my function I'd like to fire every second. It is currently made in such a way that its property, called index, is the indexPath.row of the collectionViewCell. It references to an array of event dates stored as UserDefaults. There's as many cells in the collectionView as there is events in the array.

See below the way I implemented it inside the collectionView forItemAt function:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
        // Configure the state of the cell based on the propertires of the card if reprensents
        let cardCell = cell as? EventCollectionViewCell
        
        // UI Configuration
        cardCell?.eventTitleLabel.text = ((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "events")![indexPath.row]) as! String)
        
        cardCell?.eventDateLabel.text = ("Event on: " + "\((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "dates")![indexPath.row]) as! String)")

        cardCell?.countdownLabel.text = UpdateTimeLabel(index: indexPath.row)
    
        cardCell?.eventView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
          
    }
```

The actual result is that every cell shows the time remaining between today and the event. That's already more than I thought I could do by myself!!!

[Results of actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO60V.png)

Where I think one of you can probably step-in is by helping me answering this question: **Where should a timer, looking something like the code below, be placed in order for the cardCell.countdownLabel.text to be updated every second?**

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I tried every ways I can think of and am now at a road block. I still have many more things to fix in my project, so I'm not completely stopped yet. If you need more code lines and/or precisions, let me know and I'll provide you with anything you deem helpful.

Thank you so much for taking the time to review my question,

Louis G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method `UpdateTimeLabel` method into the `EventCollectionViewCell` and modify method like this

```
@objc func UpdateTimeLabel() {
    let userCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .indian)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = userCalendar.timeZone
    
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "dates")![index] as! String)!
    
    let timeLeft = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: date)

    countdownLabel.text = "\(timeLeft.day!) days \(timeLeft.hour!) hours \(timeLeft.minute!) minutes \(timeLeft.second!) seconds"
    
}
```

After doing this add a property `index` in `EventCollectionViewCell` and on `didSet` of index fire timer in `EventCollectionViewCell` eg:

```
var index: Int {
    didSet {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }
}
```

Replace

```
cardCell?.countdownLabel.text = UpdateTimeLabel(index: indexPath.row)
```

with

```
cardCell?.index = indexPath.row
```

Comment: Thank you @satyen for your quick answer! Sadly, I end up with the same result as before: the countdown is shown, but is not updated every second. I implemented the function just as you recommended. Let me know if you need more code excerpts!

Comment: Can you please cross-check and confirm you added `timer.fire()`?

Comment: Can you please cross-check and confirm you added `timer.fire()`?

Comment: I confirm I did exactly as you recommended; timer.fire() and everything!

Comment: @SatyenChauhan superb solution! The simplest one. Could you help me with invalidating the timer. I tried it but the timer doesn't stop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found why the solution @Satyen suggested didn't work! Ok I know, it's been almost a month since his last answer, but I have to say I got pretty discouraged when I saw it didn't fix my app and decided to work on other projects, hoping someone else would jump in and offer another solution in the meanwhile. Anyways, I decided this morning to find the issue through a few sessions, and I'm proud to report I did!

Ok so here's what went wrong:
I was using a variable called "current date" as today's. This very variable was declared outside the *UpdateTimeLabel* function, and transformed in dateComponents right of the bath. Result: the current date wasn't refreshed every second, so every time the event's date was compared to *currentDate*, the result stayed the same.

Here is the working code:

```
@objc func UpdateTimeLabel() {

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current
    let todayDate = Date()
    let components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: todayDate)
    let currentDate = userCalendar.date(from: components)!
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = userCalendar.timeZone

    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "dates")![index] as! String)!

    let timeLeft = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: date)

    countdownLabel.text = "\(timeLeft.day!) days \(timeLeft.hour!) hours \(timeLeft.minute!) minutes \(timeLeft.second!) seconds"

    if currentDate >= date {

        countdownLabel.text = "Cheers! This event has occured already."
        print("An event expired.")

    }

}
```

Fired by this var index, as suggested by @Satyen:

```
var index: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTimeLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
        print("timer fired")
        
    }
}
```

Everything is now working like expected! I still have a few efficiency tweaks to make my code simpler, but overall it is now displaying the remaining time and decreasing it every second! So excited!!

Thank you to @Satyen once again for his precious input!

Comment: Have you figured out how to invalidate the timer?